# is there any formula for this subset generation problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

We can generate all subsets by converting numbers into binary from 0 to $2^n-1$. for example $n = 6$.The integer corresponding to each subset with size 1,2,...6 is shown below

Size 1= $32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1$

Size 2=$48, 40, 36, 34, 33, 24, 20, 18, 17, 12, 10, 9, 6, 5, 3$

Size 3=$56, 52, 50, 49, 44, 42, 41, 38, 37, 35, 28, 26, 25, 22, 21, 19, 14, 13, 11, 7$

Size 4=$60, 58, 57, 54, 53, 51, 46, 45, 43, 39, 30, 29, 27, 23, 15$

Size 5=$62, 61, 59, 55, 47, 31$

size 6=$63$

Suppose I want to find out all the integers corresponding to size 3 subsets, given $n=6$, how could I get the series directly. I mean is there any way to get the corresponding integers without conversion from binary to integer.

Comment: You mean without converting from integer to binary? Because in binary it is obvious how to get them, with integers it might be a little harder...

Comment: Yes, I want the reverse. I mean to get the series by means of any formula without going through the binary to integer conversion. Yes in binary it is easy to get just by sliding bit position.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to proceed.

Comment: You probably misunderstood my problem. To get the subset we must convert an integer to binary. But, the question is how would we get integers for a particular size subset.

Comment: Well, we write down the binaries and convert them, I don't see an easier way right now (unless we just use a look-up table like you wrote down there).

Answer (score 2):

Well, kind-of, but  it could be accused of being binary-in-disguise. And it's only given by recursion.

Call the sequences $s_n$ for $n$ members. Now any number in such a series $s_n(j)$ is either the double of a previous number in the same series or one larger than a number in the preceding series. Or put in formula language $s_n(j) = 2s_n(k)$ (for some $k<j$) or $s_n(j) = 2s_{n-1}(l)+1$ (for some $l$).

Note that by this scheme you don't have to consider all $k$s and $l$s since they will be used in sequence:

$$\begin{align}
s_3(0) &= 2s_2(0)+1 &= 7 && l = 0\\ 
s_3(1) &= 2s_2(1)+1 &= 11 && l = 1\\
s_3(2) &= 2s_2(2)+1 &= 13 && l = 2\\
s_3(3) &= 2s_3(0)   &= 14 && j = 0\\
s_3(4) &= 2s_2(3)+1 &= 19 && l = 3 \\
s_3(5) &= 2s_2(4)+1 &= 21 && l = 4 \\
s_3(6) &= 2s_3(1) &= 22 && j = 1\\
\vdots 
\end{align}$$

This is of course binary-in-disguise since what we do is to shift the binary number to the right, if by doing that we lose a $1$ we would find the resulting binary number in the previous sequence. Otherwise we would find the number in the same sequence. Or put in another way, a binary number has three ones if it's either the right shift of a three-one-binary or it's the right shift of a two-ones-binary except with the least significant set to one.

Comment: Thanks, I liked this recursion. One doubt, is there any way to know when to use j?

Comment: @NARAYANCHANGDER Yes, you use the least of $2s_3(k)$ and $2s_2(l)+1$ (and increase the corresponding index). Of course you have to handle the exception when $k=l=0$ when you haven't calculated $s_3(0)$ yet.